# Adobe CQ5 error log warning when tagging content

Tags: osgi, xss, aem, sling

When I edit the page properties of a page and add a tag, the following warning appears in the error log. In this example I added the ootb orientation tag:

`19.12.2013 16:27:18.022 *WARN* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1387488438020] GET /etc/tags/properties/orientation.tag.json HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.commons.JSONWriterUtil XSS protection service was not provided or not available while processing key [description]`

When I add the tag, CQ makes the following json request:

```
http://localhost:4502/etc/tags/properties/orientation.tag.json
```

My environment is a fresh CQ5.5 author instance. Adobe's Service pack 3 doesn't fix the warning. CQ's XSS Protection Service (XSSProtectionServiceImpl) is active in the osgi console. Adding a description to the tag didn't help. The warning happens for all tags. What can I do to make this warning go away? Is there some configuration I need to add?